# How is Spy++ element highlighting working?

Tags: user-interface, automation, highlighting, highlight, spy++

I'm using the Spy++ for my work with the MS UI Automation Framework, so i wanted to ask you if you know how the search / highlighting gui elements from the spy++ works.

i'm talking about this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m1G4.png

you cant see the mouse on the screen, but if you press the left mouse key over a ui component he can read and highlight all the information. 
I'm sure he uses the fromPoint() function to find the component under the mouse:

```
System.Windows.Point point = new System.Windows.Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromPoint(point);
```

but i cant tell how he draws the border. is there a pattern / function in the ui framework ? couldnt find something like this in the framework api only a way with win32 ( ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectangle is probably "drawn" on top of the screen using the [BoundingRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.boundingrectangleproperty.aspx) property.

(Just a guess).

Comment: the BoundingRectangle helps a lot, so i can get the position and size. Now the question is how they draw on top of the other application, i'm new @ .net GUI Programming. usally you can only draw on your forms ?

Comment: You can draw ontop of anything by have a window with transparent background: WindowStyle="None"; ShowInTaskbar="False"; AllowsTransparency="True"; Background="Transparent".

Comment: It is NOT BoundingRectangle. BoundingRectangle is a rectangle. The highlight of Spy++ successfully follows non-rectangular borders.